# How to show $\int_{0}^{t} s \mathop{dW_{s}} = tW_{t} - \int_{0}^{t} W_{s} \mathop{ds}$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm new to stochastic integration, and I've been stuck on this exercise. I want to show $$\int_{0}^{t} s \mathop{dW_{s}} = tW_{t} - \int_{0}^{t} W_{s} \mathop{ds}$$

holds, but I don't really know how to do so. My book doesn't have very many examples, so I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Integration_by_parts

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1179346/36150) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785928/36150)

Answer (score 0):

Apply Ito's Lemma on $sW_s$, i.e. (in it's differential form) write $\mathrm d(sW_s)=\dots$

You should see the two terms appear, then by integration between $0$ and $t$ you have it.

Answer (score 0):

We know: $W_0=0$.

By Ito Lemma:

$$
\begin{align}
& d(tW_t) = W_tdt+tdW_t\\
\Rightarrow & tW_t = \int_0^tW_sds +\int_0^tsdW_s\\
\Rightarrow & \int_0^tsdW_s = tW_t -\int_0^tW_sds
\end{align}
$$